# Understanding the 95% confidence interval

Tags: r, confidence-interval

I am new to statistics, and recently came over interval confidence, but did not understand very well. Will you please explain this to me. to better understand, i will put an example as well:

Lets say there are 5000 products in a store and we are checking the expiry date of them. We selected 113 products and from these 113, we found that 61 of them were expired. How to determine the 95% confidence interval of the proportion for this, and what does it mean.

I am used to R, so solving this problem in R will help me.

Thank you.